# How to set `data` attribute of Ajax request dynamically in javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have javascript function that will be called from a few pages when `Kendo.Button()` is clicked.

This is a `Kendo.Button()`:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("btnSubmit")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", title= "Report1", url = "/Controller1/Method1/"  })
                    .Icon("k-icon k-i-file-txt")
                    .Content("View Details")
                    .Events(e => e.Click("ShowDetails"))

)
```

This button will have different number of parameters defined in `.HtmlAttribute` property depending on a page. One page will have 3 parameters another will have just one.

When the button is clicked on either page the following `javascript` will be called:

This is my `JavaScript`:

```
function ShowDetails() {
    var URL = this.element.attr("url")
    $('#win_wnd_title').text(this.element.attr("title"));
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: URL,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "html",
            data: ?
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                var dialog = $("#win").data("kendoWindow");
                $("#dataWin").html(result);
                dialog.open();
                showLoaderPopup();
            }
        })
}
```

I need to set `data` attribute dynamically, so when the function is called from one page, I do not need to set parameters to `data` attribute. In another case I need to do that. So, it will be something like that in the function:

```
If (flag == 1) 
{
   var myData =  JSON.stringify({ ID: id, Amount: amount, Desc: desc });
}
else
{
   var myData = null 
}
```

Then in the function I set the `data` property for Ajax request:

```
$.ajax(
   {
      .
      .
      .
      data: myData 
   }
)
```

So, only on a particular Button, the parameters will be sent.

How can I do that, so I do not repeat the same Ajax logic twice just to change the `data` parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I would make it comment, however i dont have enought reputation for that.

I would approach it pretty much like you described. I would add another parameter to button:

```
Button()
  .Name("btnSubmit")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", title= "Report1", url = "/Controller1/Method1/", sendData = "true" })
  .Icon("k-icon k-i-file-txt")
  .Content("View Details")
  .Events(e => e.Click("ShowDetails"))
)
```

And then create local variable with data based on that html parameter.
Something like that:

```
function ShowDetails() {
    var URL = $(sender).data('url');
    var myData = null;

    if($(sender).data('sendData') == "true")
    {
        myData = JSON.stringify({ ID: id, Amount: amount, Desc: desc });
    }

    $.ajax(
    {
        ...

        data: myData
        success: function (result) {
        ...
        }
    })
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That worked. Should have tried before asking. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy coding